# dbt Python Incremental Models

Tags: python, google-bigquery, dbt

I’m really excited to be able to use Python models in dbt, but I’ve been running into issues with incremental ones.

If I have a working model with `materialized = "table"` and I change it to `materialized = "incremental"`, shouldn’t that work fine even before adding in the correct `if dbt.is_incremental:` logic?

For some reason I get this error when I just change table → incremental for a working model:

```
File "/tmp/d87435d6-edb3-4afa-84e7-04dae648adcf/query_consistency.py", line 5
    create or replace table graph-mainnet.internal_metrics.query_consistency__dbt_tmp
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Any thoughts here? Has anyone else had issues with python incremental models? I'm using bigquery.

Code which works fine below (and does not work fine when going from table to incremental):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import time

def model(dbt, session):
    dbt.config(materialized = "table")

    # ENTER THE SCHEMA TYPE YOU WANT TO GET ALL DATA FOR
    schema_type = 'dex-amm'
    
    # fetch the data from the deployment file
    response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/messari/subgraphs/master/deployment/deployment.json')
    subgraphs = response.json()
    
    # create query
    query = '''{
      financialsDailySnapshots(orderBy: timestamp, orderDirection: desc, first: 365) {
        cumulativeVolumeUSD
        dailyProtocolSideRevenueUSD
        totalValueLockedUSD
        cumulativeTotalRevenueUSD
        dailyTotalRevenueUSD
        dailyVolumeUSD
        timestamp
      }
    }'''
    
    base_url = 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/messari/'
    data = []
    for project in subgraphs:
        for deployment in subgraphs[project]['deployments']:
            schema = subgraphs[project]['schema']
            status = subgraphs[project]['deployments'][deployment]['status']
            if status != 'prod' or schema != schema_type:
                continue
            if len(data) >= 4:  # check if we've reached the subgraphs limit
                break
            try: # need this because not all have hosted-service field
                slug = subgraphs[project]['deployments'][deployment]['services']['hosted-service']['slug']
            except KeyError:
                print(f"KeyError: unable to extract data from '{slug}' for '{project}'")   
            response = requests.post(base_url + slug, json={'query': query})
            time.sleep(1)
            if response.ok:
                response_json = response.json()
                headers = response.headers
                timestamp_query = headers.get('Date')
                try:
                    data.append((project, deployment, timestamp_query, response_json['data']['financialsDailySnapshots']))
                    print(f"Got data for: {slug}")
                except KeyError:
                    print(f"KeyError: unable to extract data from '{slug}' for '{project}'")
            else:
                print(f'Request failed for {base_url + slug} with status {response.status_code}')
            if len(data) >= 4:  # check if we've reached the subgraphs limit
                break
    
    # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['project', 'deployment', 'timestamp_query', 'data'])
    # adjust df
    df = df.explode('data')
    df = pd.concat([df.drop(['data'], axis=1), df['data'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
    # convert timestamp
    df['timestamp_query'] = df['timestamp_query'].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
    df['timestamp_query'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_query'], format='%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
    # identifier
    df['product'] = 'hosted_service'
    # return result
    return df
```

Comment: Based on the dbt docs, you should add the condition  `if dbt.is_incremental:` , so that dbt will parse it as an incremental model correctly. Link:  https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/python-models#accessing-project-context

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I didn't have a unique_id. Currently, dbt only supports merge as an incremental strategy for bigquery for python models. In addition to the condition `if dbt.is_incremental`, you should also make sure that you are defining a unique_id in your config because merge as incremental strategy requires it. [How dbt configs work for bigquery](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/bigquery-configs)

Edit:

This also appears to be an issue on the dbt side that was fixed in version 1.4.2 for the bigquery adapter. [PR describing issue on dbt's bigquery repository](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-bigquery/issues/581)